# Specify configuration settings per pytest test

Tags: python, pytest

I manage my configuration for a Python application with https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv and I use `pytest` for my tests.

For a particular set of tests, I want custom configuration specific to each test. Now I know of https://github.com/quiqua/pytest-dotenv, which gives me the ability to set a config per environment (prod/test), but I want finer granularity on a per-test basis. So far, I've handled this by mocking the `Config` object that contains all of my configuration. This is messy because for each test, I need to mock this `Config` object for each module where it's loaded.

Ideally, I'd have something like this:

```
def test_1(config):
    config.foo = 'bar'
    run_code_that_uses_config()

def test_2(config):
    config.foo = 'bleh'
    run_code_that_uses_config()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `monkeypatch` and going with this approach:

```
from my_library.settings import Config

@pytest.fixture
def config(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(Config, 'foo', 'bar')
    return Config


def test_1(config, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(config, 'foo', 'some value specific to this test')
    run_code_that_uses_config()
```

With `monkeypatch` I was able to pass around the `Config` object via a pytest fixture to create a default and override it for each test. The code that uses the config was able to pick up the change. Previously, I'd used `patch` from the standard `mock` library, but I had to patch every single place where the config was looked up (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch), which made maintenance difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation, however I set as a config variable and use the `current_app` to modify at the test, for eg.

```
import pytest
from flask import current_app

@pytest.mark.usefixtures(...)
def test_my_method(client, session)
    # Initially, it was False, but I modified here as True
    current_app.config['MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE'] = True
    ...
    # Then, do your test here
```

Hope it helps!